# Granting pernissions in SAP HANA Express Edition

Tags: hana

I'm trying to run the following statement in SAP HANA 2.0 Express Edition using SYSTEM user:

```
Grant select on schema DB001 to USER002;
```

I get the following error:

> Could not execute 'Grant select on schema DB001 to USER002'
>
> SAP DBTech JDBC: [258]: insufficient privilege: Not authorized

What user is the admin user authorized to granting privileges? Is it SYS? If yes what's its password (I never set it up when I installed Hana)

Comment: There's not a such an almighty user. The creator of the schema, for example, could execute that statement with grant option. If you're doing some development more serious than just exploring, it is generally better to create a role and grant that role (and also not using SYSTEM). Who created the schema? How?

Comment: Gracias, Lucia!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem.
Usually, we have more than one schemas in SAP HANA
For example:
SYSTEM
SAPABAP1

You log in with SYSTEM superuser and want to execute:

> GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA SAPABAP1 TO USER;

Output:

> Could not execute 'GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA SAPABAP1 TO USER' SAP DBTech
> JDBC: [258]: insufficient privilege: Detailed info for this error can
> be found with guid '681FE1E7F8F5B949A0CA764D802C3C4D'

Resolution log-in as SAPABAP1 (schema owner)

And execute GRANT statement again.